# How to exclude component from caching using Nuxt.js?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am trying to use Vue.js `keep-alive` prop in Nuxt.js, I am trying to cache all components except one, this is `basket` component which I want to exclude from caching, Every time when user will add an item to the basket I want to show component and load data again, I have tried this trick It does not seem to work, What would be the best solution?

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <TheHeader />
      <Nuxt keep-alive :keep-alive-props="{exclude: ['basket']}" />
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check in your devtools that the proper props are set, because this is the correct syntax indeed.

[image]

Double check that you also do have those components inside of it. And that the other ones (the ones you want to include) are properly cached.
If it's still not working, please show us the `Basket` component or make a reproduction.

It also depends on how you load/access your data actually. It is not that simple on some points and depends on vuex/middlewares etc.