# How to include specific component for caching Using Nuxt.js keep-alive props?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have only one component I would like to keep cached in my Nuxt.js app.

```
<template>
 <v-container>
   <nuxt keep-alive :keep-alive-props={ include: ['pages/settings/games.vue'] } />
 </v-container> 
</template>
```

This seems to cache every page I have in my application.
I would like to just cache single page specified inside of `include` prop.

How can I cache single page with `keep-alive`?

Comment: If this is the syntax in the doc, it should work great. Can you confirm if it is getting all of them or just this one? Check your Vue devtools. Also, keep alive is usually used for a component or can it also be used for a page? (I don't remember)

Comment: This is how to see that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67701468/8816585

Comment: I have been checking Vue Devtools on every page and it says:

keepAlive: true;
keepAliveProps: Object
  exclude: Array[1]
   0: "pages/settings/games.vue"

Comment: include*, not exclude, pardon

Comment: So, it should work fine (with a component name, not a path). Double check it again to be sure if it works or not.

Comment: Okay, so do I write > include: ['pages/settings/games.vue'] or > include: ['games.vue'] ?

Comment: Second one, as shown in the doc: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/nuxt-components#keep-alive

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve this by giving specific component that I want to keep with `keep-alive` a `name` property.

So it was actually `<nuxt keep-alive :keep-alive-props="{ include: ['games'] }" />` then in my component I specified `name: 'games'`.

Hope this helps somebody.